# Prove or disprove that if $A$ is a local ring, then $A[X]/\langle X^n\rangle$ is local ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, local-rings

I can prove that it is true when $A$ is a field. When $A$ is a field any $\langle X\rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $A[X]$. Any maximal ideal of $A[X]/\langle X^n\rangle$ is of the form $M/\langle X^n\rangle$ for some maximal ideal $M$ of $A[X]$ containing $X^n$. As $M$ is maximal, $M$ is prime and $X^n\in M\implies X\in M\implies\langle X\rangle \subseteq M\implies M=\langle X\rangle$. This proves $\langle X\rangle/\langle X^n\rangle $ is the only maximal ideal of $A[X]/\langle X^n\rangle$.

But I'm unable to conclude anything for any local ring $A$. Can anyone help complete the solution? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hint : ideals of $R/I$ are in inclusion-preserving bijection with ideals of $R$ that contain $I$. This is the fourth (lattice) isomorphism theorem for rings.

Comment: Yes using this any maximal ideal of $A[X]/\langle X^n\rangle$ is of the form $M/\langle X^n\rangle$ where $M$ is maximal ideal of $A[X]$ with $X^n\in M$, as $M$ is prime too, $X\in M$, so $\langle X\rangle\subseteq M$. Now if  $A$ is not field, then $\langle X\rangle$ is not maximal ideal, from here I cannot proceed. Though I have not used $A$ is local ring yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, a given maximal ideal corresponds to $M/(X^n)$ where where $M\lhd A[X]$ is a maximal ideal.  Then  as you discovered $(X)\subseteq M$.  And since $A[X]/(X)\cong A$, the maximal ideals of the former correspond to those of the latter. If $A$ is local, then there is only one maximal ideal of the latter ring, hence only one maximal ideal of the former ring.